# Cat 6a cable with 2 ports socket?

Tags: networking, routing, lan

I have moved to a new house and wanted to setup in-house networking. In 4 rooms, there are sockets with 2 Ethernet ports mounted into the walls. In the entire house, it makes a total of 8 Ethernet ports, but in the network box, I see only 4 cables. I have figured out that every single cable in the box ends in each socket with two ports. I have never seen such thing ever, can somebody explain it to me how it works?

My idea is to put a router in the network box and connect it with all the 4 cables. What is very intriguing for me is that one cable ends with two ports. How will that work? If I connect 2 devices on the same cable, will that work properly? Will the router properly recognize both devices? Do I need any specialized router? Does this technology have any name?

I am attaching a picture of the network box and pictures of the socket. You can see that there goes only one cable to the socket, but socket has two ports.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I will be thankful for every answer. The more it is detailed, the better. I am working myself in IT (software engineering), so it is a shame to not know what is going on with my own network in my own house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean, “how it works”? Only one of the two ports is connected. It’s super simple.

Why would anyone do this? Because from my experience, two-port jacks are much easier to acquire.

Comment: Ohh I didn't figure out there is only one port connected, I thought this cable hooks both ports. I must be blind. Thank you very much for your answer and for the explanation why would somebody do this!

Answer (score 0):

> What is very intriguing for me is that one cable ends with two ports.
>   How will that work?

The socket might have 2 ports but only the one connected to the orange cable will be functional and connected to your network.

[image]

> If I connect 2 devices on the same cable, will that work properly?
>   Will the router properly recognize both devices?

Only the device connected to the orange cable will be connected to your network.

> Does this technology have any name?

It is called IEEE 802.3

> In the entire house, it makes a total of 8 Ethernet ports, but in the
>   network box, I see only 4 cables.

If you only see 4 cables in the network box, it means in your entire house, you actually only have 4 Ethernet ports.

> Do I need any specialized router?

Any router which can support 4 Ethernet devices will work.

Comment: I didn't notice that there goes one cable per port! Thank you for your answer!